# Imageviews in a linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add 4 imageViews to a verticaly aligned LinearLayout. I want the four images to be perfectly stacked with no spacing. The problem is that there is empty space above and below the images. Maybe this has something to do with the way the images get scaled?

Here is my source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.ads.AdView
         xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
         android:id="@+id/add1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId=""
         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
         ads:testDevices="" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/add1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_graphic_1"/>

             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/menu_graphic_2" />
            <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/menu_graphic_3" />

             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/menu_graphic_4" />

        </LinearLayout>

     </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try to display images as background not source ,
android:background="@drawable/menu_graphic_3".

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "empty space above and below", is this between the `ImageView's` or is it within? Have you tried to add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your `ImageView's`?

Comment: Or set `ScaleType`, [for example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) `android:scaleType="fitXY"` will fill the `ImageView`, meaning it will stretch the image to fit.

Comment: can you show as image how you actually want ? i get perfectly no space above image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asok is right. Adding android:adjustViewBounds="true" to my ImageView's fixed the problem :)